# Change background color of a box when an element is dropped on top of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jQuery, I have a draggable element called `dropblock` whose `revert` parameter is set to `true`. When `dropblock` is dropped on a list of boxes called `blocks`, I would like the box onto which it is dropped - and its two immediate neighbors - to change their background color (say to red) before `dropblock` reverts back to its original position. But being a JavaScript beginner, I don't know how to get started on doing this. Is there some way to tell which box the mouse was hovering over when `dropblock` gets dropped?

Here is what my code looks like after stripping off everything not relevant to this question:

MVCE.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Stackexchange MVCE</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script src="MVCE.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="MVCE.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul id="blocks">
         <li class="ui-state-default" id="block-1"></li>
         <li class="ui-state-default" id="block-2"></li>
         <li class="ui-state-default" id="block-3"></li>
         <li class="ui-state-default" id="block-4"></li>
         <li class="ui-state-default" id="block-5"></li>
         <li class="ui-state-default" id="block-6"></li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="dropblock">
         <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

MVCE.css:

```
#blocks { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px; 
}

#blocks li { 
    margin: 3px 3px 0px 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

#dropblock { 
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
}

#dropblock li {
    margin: 3px 3px 0px 0;
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

MVCE.js:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dropblock" ).draggable({ 
        revert: true});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements `#blocks li` need to be [droppable](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/), therefore you would invoke the [`.droppable()` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/).

Within the [`drop` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop), you would access the element that is being dropped into and its adjacent sibling elements. In this example, the `.active` class is being added to the target element and its siblings (using the `.next()`/`.prev()` methods). The `.active` class is also being removed from all previously active elements too.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/yzkckjfq/)

```
$('#dropblock').draggable({
    revert: true
});

$('#blocks li').droppable({
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $('#blocks li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).add($(this).next()).add($(this).prev()).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Change the [`tolerance` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance) to your liking.  In the example above, it it set to `touch`, because draggable/droppable elements are the same size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .droppable() on each of the boxes. Then you can access the next and previous siblings to change their colour.